# Laravel doesn't drop table on rollback or refresh

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new migration called "listings", I basically just followed TraversyMedia's crash course to help my learning process of PHP and Laravel.

I wanted to add a simple modification to the listings migration so it references a user ID (the 'poster').

I did that like this:

```php
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```

I did migrate:refresh, even tried migrate:rollback then migrate again, but still: whatever I do, the listings table will never be dropped, I have to do it manually. Every other table gets dropped but this and I don't understand why.

It had a "down" function too:

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('listings');
}
```

Did I do something wrong? Did I miss something?

I use: Laravel 9.38.0, PHP 8.1.10 with Zend Engine v4.1.10

Comment: in your `/config/database.php` file, search for `mysql` entry and change `'engine' => null,` to `'engine' => 'InnoDB',`. This will solve your problem I guess

Comment: Wow, it worked! Could you submit this as an answer + explanation? Then I can approve it as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using **MyISAM storage engine**.

**MyISAM** is a non-transactional storage type, and any write option needs to be rolled back manually (if needed). **InnoDB** is a transaction storage type that automatically rollbacks the writes if they are not completed.

In your `/config/database.php` file change `mysql` data as :

```
'engine' => null,
```

to

```
'engine' => 'InnoDB',
```

This above method will apply on your all database tables.

If you want to use **InnoDB** on specific table then add this line on your migration file as :

```
Schema::create('listings', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    // ...
});
```

See [Database Connection & Table Options](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#database-connection-table-options)